# How to symbolically solve a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, symbolic-computation

A fellow user had an interesting question:

> **Less-tedious way of solving this system of linear equations?**
>
> Is there a shortcut to solving for $w_1, w_2, w_3$ in $$
>   \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}  1 & 1 & 1\\  \frac{3}{4}a+\frac{1}{4}b &
>  \frac{1}{2}a+\frac{1}{2}b & \frac{1}{4}a+\frac{3}{4}b\\
>   (\frac{3}{4}a+\frac{1}{4}b)^2 & (\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{1}{2}b)^2 &
>  (\frac{1}{4}a+\frac{3}{4}b)^2\\  \end{array} \right]  \cdot
>   \left[ \begin{array}{c}  w_1\\  w_2\\  w_3  \end{array} \right]  =
>   \left[ \begin{array}{c}  b-a\\  \frac{b^2-a^2}{2}\\
>   \frac{b^3-a^3}{3}  \end{array} \right]   $$ where $a, b$ are
>   constants? (I'm trying to derive the formula for a 3-point open
>   Newton-Cotes quadrature rule.) Thanks!

Unfortunately the question was deleted ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2004814/86776)), but I think it might be interesting in general.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the free [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) computer algebra system.

You can enter your matrix like this:

```
A: matrix(
 [1,1,1], 
 [(3/4)*a+(1/4)*b,(1/2)*a+(1/2)*b,(1/4)*a+(3/4)*b], 
 [((3/4)*a+(1/4)*b)^2,((1/2)*a+(1/2)*b)^2,((1/4)*a+(3/4)*b)^2]
 );
```

$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\
\frac{b}{4}+\frac{3a}{4} & \frac{b}{2}+\frac{a}{2} & \frac{3b}{4}+\frac{a}{4}\\
{{\left( \frac{b}{4}+\frac{3a}{4}\right) }^{2}} & {{\left( \frac{b}{2}+\frac{a}{2}\right) }^{2}} & {{\left( \frac{3b}{4}+\frac{a}{4}\right) }^{2}}\end{pmatrix}
$$
and the result vector like that:

```
bcol: matrix(
 [b-a], 
 [(b^2-a^2)/2], 
 [(b^3-a^3)/3]
);
```

$$
\begin{pmatrix}b-a\\
\frac{{{b}^{2}}-{{a}^{2}}}{2}\\
\frac{{{b}^{3}}-{{a}^{3}}}{3}\end{pmatrix}
$$
This command will solve your linear system by $LU$ decomposition:

```
ls : linsolve_by_lu(A,bcol);
```

You extract and simplify the solution vector like this:

```
xycol: ratsimp(first(ls));
```

$$
\begin{pmatrix}\frac{2b-2a}{3}\\
-\frac{b-a}{3}\\
\frac{2b-2a}{3}\end{pmatrix}
$$
where `first` picks the first element of the result and `ratsimp` is one of Maxima's simplification functions.

With this you can verify the result:

```
ratsimp(A . xycol);
```

$$
\begin{pmatrix}b-a\\
\frac{{{b}^{2}}-{{a}^{2}}}{2}\\
\frac{{{b}^{3}}-{{a}^{3}}}{3}\end{pmatrix}
$$
Note that Maxima uses a dot for the matrix multiplication operator.

Answer (score 1):

One can also make use of the Mathematica programming language and proceed as follows:

[image: screenshot of the interactive session where we solve the system with the Mathematica programming language]

where the lines with *MatrixForm[$\cdots$]* were just to check if the matrices were fine.

The command *LinearSolve[matrix, result]* finds the solution and the added *// MatrixForm* is just for pretty printing.